# How to add all top cells in present cell of a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example.
Let us assume we are having below dataframe:

```
    Num
0    2 
1    4 
2    1 
3    5 
4    3
```

The expected output in another "sum" should be as below:

```
    Num   sum
0    2    2
1    4    6 (2+4)
2    1    7 (2+4+1)
3    5    12 (2+4+1+5)
4    3    15 (2+4+1+5+3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

`df['sum'] = df['Num'].cumsum()`